# UIPopover in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a UIViewcontroller, with a button. When I press the button it triggers a segue to a popover view (the segue is set through storyboard, not through the codes). When the popover is dismissed (by pressing outside of its bounds), I want the initial view controller to reload. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the delegate of the popover controller in your `prepareSegue:` method and implement the delegate method `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` which will be called when the popver is dismissed.
You can get the popover controller with `UIPopoverController *popover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController]`